# Box API .NET SDK: "pad block corrupted" exception when instantiating BoxJWTAuth

Tags: box-api, box

I'm using the Box SDK for .NET and just trying to get started authenticating using the Java Web Token workflow. I'm using code that's pretty much the same as the code sample that's included in the SDK's code examples.

```
var jwtPrivateKey = File.ReadAllText("private_key.pem");

var boxConfig = new BoxConfig(ClientId, ClientSecret, EnterpriseId, jwtPrivateKey, JwtPrivateKeyPassword, JwtPublicKeyId);

var boxJwt = new BoxJWTAuth(boxConfig);
```

But at that last line I'm getting an exception that says "pad block corrupted". The stack trace seems to indicate that it involves reading the private key, but I don't see what I could be doing wrong considering this is basically the same as the code sample (https://github.com/box/box-windows-sdk-v2/blob/master/Box.V2.Samples.JWTAuth/Program.cs).

Any ideas?

Comment: This does sound like a formatting issue with the private key. How did you generate it? If you used the Cygwin method, you might instead try using the [OpenSSL binary for Windows](https://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html).

Comment: @JohnHoerr I did use Cygwin, yes... I just regenerated the private key and now it works. I suspect I opened the previous private key in Notepad and maybe accidentally made some change to it.

Comment: Nice! Go ahead and accept your answer as correct so that folks will know the problem is solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After re-generating the private key with Cygwin, things are working for me.

I believe what happened was I opened the private key in Notepad or something, then saved it in some format it didn't like (maybe changed encoding to UTF-8, or saved it with Windows-style line breaks).

Comment: I battled with this for several hours and the only way I found to fix it was to start with all new keys and passwords. It seems to be caused by something mis-matched.